# Logging from XamlTaskFactory with `MessageImportance.high`

Tags: c#, xaml, msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0

I'm using `XamlTaskFactory` to create an MSBuild Task which runs an external command line utility with a set of parameters. This command line utility is sending its output to standard output.

Tasks created with `XamlTaskFactory` inherit from `ToolTask`, which [sends stdout to log, but **with low importance** by default](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/bec6ba780d0b2f74e3b898f09fe7787d709b2bb5/src/Utilities/ToolTask.cs#L376).

I would like to send my task's stdout to log **with high importance**. (and only affect this task's logging importance).
Unfortunately, tasks created with `XamlTaskFactory` do not override the [`StandardOutputLoggingImportance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.tooltask.standardoutputloggingimportance%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) attribute, so stdout from such tasks is always sent to log with low importance.

#### Is there a way to create a new MsBuild inline task (using `CodeTaskFactory`) which somehow inherits and extends my task (which was created with `XamlTaskFactory`) and overrides `StandardOutputLoggingImportance` property?

If I could do that, logs from my task would be sent with high importance. But I'm not sure how to inherit a custom task from another task that was created with `XamlTaskFactory`...

Other ideas how to achieve this are welcome.

---

### Update

I just missed a very simple solution:
set `StandardErrorImportance="High"` on the task (which was created with `XamlTaskFactory`).

A lot of other attributes can be set as described in [`XamlDataDrivenToolTask` Class documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.tasks.xaml.xamldatadriventooltask.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).